# I have the operands and operation of an expression stored in separate variables, how can I evaluate?

Tags: python, variables

So, for example, I have

`a=2
 b= +
 c= 3`

How can I use these variables to evaluate 2+3?

Comment: You can't store `+` in a variable, unless it's a string. Show us your actual code, tell us what you've tried and what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator` module contains functions that implement the built-in operators. You can build a dictionary that maps the operator's particular symbol to the corresponding function, then use that as a look-up table to evaluate your expression.

```
import operator
>>> op_dict = { '+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub }
>>> a = 2
>>> b = '+'
>>> c = 3
>>> op_dict[b](a, c)
5
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `+` to a variable. What you can do is to store its "string representation":

```
a = 2
b = '+'
c = 3
```

To evaluate the operation you can use `eval()`:

```
>>> print eval(str(a) + b + str(c))
5
```

which will evaluate the expression passed as a string (that's why we use first `str(a)`, to get a whole string)

**Note:**

- If there is another way that prevemts you to use `eval`, use it.
- You have to be very careful while using `eval`, because you may get unexpected results.
- There is another function called `exec()` which is used to execute statements.